# Angular 5 best practice for updating a single object with RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm building an Angular 5 application that let's you track the score of an ongoing martial arts match. The score is input into the DB from a desktop application.
The webapp then gets the score as a single scoreboard object from a Angular service that calls an API with the Id for the match and uses the retrieved object in the component to display the score for the two fighters. 
The user will refreshes the score by a button click (or maybe on a timer.)

I'm very new to both Angular and RxJs, and the trouble I'm having is finding a examples of how to do this WELL.

Right now I've got it working by getting scoreboards for ALL matches and then using map and find to filter out the one I want. It feels very crude.

To summarize what I need to do.
Make a call to a service method with a unique Id.
Get a single object from the API with the Id.
return that object to the component and assign it to a property.

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the api that you are calling supports method that would fetch only one match's scores by it's unique ID then you can just call it and pass the id instead of calling another endpoint that fetches everything

Comment: Do you mean RxJS ? Or you actually use angular AND react in the same webpage ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @c69 I mean RxJS. I  corrected the question. Sorry.

Comment: `myService.getObjectFromAPI (id).pipe (first ()).subscribe (v => doStuff (v));`

Comment: But if you want to do it properly - maybe you want to store it as observable, and just render with angular's `async` pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your service, you should have a method that returns single `Score`. Something like:

```
getSingleScore(id:string):Observable<Score>{
   return yourHttpCallToAPI...
}
```

Then in your component, you can have a property that gets that `Observable`:

```
singleScore$:Observable<Score>;

ngOnInit(){
   this.singleScore$ = myService.getSingleScore(id);
}
```

finally, in your template, bind `singleScore$` with `async` pipe:

```
<div *nfIg="singleScore$ | async as score">Whatever property: {{score.whatever}}</div>
```

PS.

`...*nfIg="singleScore$ | async as score"` is a good practice since that way you resolve `async` only once and not as many times as you have properties you want to show.

ref: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-conditional-result-in-a-variable

Comment: Thanks a lot!
How does the async pipe method compare to making singleScorea plain Score and assigning it in .suscribe on myService.getSingleScore(id)?

Like:
singleScore: Score;

myService.getSingleScore(id).subscribe(score => this.singleScore = score)

Comment: then you have to manage that subscription and make sure you unsubscribe in components `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook